# ZPL print barcode with extra text above

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am developing an application that prints labels using Zebra GK420t printer.
I successfully could print Barcode with the text value in the bottom of the Barcode.

However, I was not be able to print extra text above the Barcode.

I am using this command

```
^XA
^FO20,20^BY2
^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FDvar^FS
^XZ
```

[Translated to ZPL from program code]

Which, if var is 'abc123', prints the Barcode with abc123 underneath.

Q: How can for example can I print my name above the Barcode???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean "abc123 above the barcode" then change `^BCN,100,Y,N,N` to `^BCN,100,Y,Y,N`.

If you mean "Print 'Nabeel' above the barcode" then insert

```
^CFD^FDNabeel^FS
^FO20,50
```

After the ^FO20,20 line.

This would select internal font "D" (CFD) and print "Nabeel" at offset 20,20 (the preceding (^FO)) then set the position of the barcode to 20,50 since 20,20 is really close to top-left of the label.

I'll presume you know how to modify your program code.